# i dont understand how can I put an amount in these letters?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
totalBought = float(input("how much you bought in total:")) 
discountAmt = input("what is your status:")
if discountAmt == "S":
    S == 10
elif discountAmt == "O":
    O == 5
elif discountAmt == "M":
    M == 15
elif discountAmt == "E":
    E == 20

totalPrice = totalBought - discountAmt

print(totalPrice)
```

### These letters are discounts ,students,old people,pwds,and vips

Comment: `==` is comparison, `=` is assignment. That said, you need one variable/name for the discount, not 4 different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using `==` which returns a boolean, use `=` to assign a variable.
Secondly, no need to create different variables. Just use one `S` to assign discounts.

Refer to the solution below:

```
totalBought = float(input("how much you bought in total:")) 
discountAmt = input("what is your status:")

if discountAmt == "S":
    S = 10
elif discountAmt == "O":
    S = 5
elif discountAmt == "M":
    S = 15
elif discountAmt == "E":
    S = 20

totalPrice = totalBought - S
print(totalPrice)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something with Using Dictionary:

Using Dictionary code is more more readable and less if else condition

```
totalBought = float(input("how much you bought in total:"))
discountDict ={
     'S':10,
     'O': 5,
     'M':15,
     'E':20

}
discountAmt = input("what is your status:")


totalPrice = totalBought - discountDict[discountAmt]

print(totalPrice)
```

Answer (score 2):

On the second line, `discountAmt` is assigned a string value. That string value remains its value throughout the code. And so when you do `totalBought - discountAtm`, you do a number minus a string, which doesn't make sense. Also, you need to distinguish between `==` and `=`. What you can do is replace all those `S == 10`, `O == 5`, etc. with `discoutAmt = 10`, `discountAmt = 5`, etc. Or, you can dedicate a separate variable to the discount amount, if you don't want to override the discount code.